# Ubuntu VM on Azure cannot login after restore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, azure

I have performed a restore operation for an Ubuntu VM and now it says access denied when I try to login with the same password. Also when I tried to reset password/ssh configuration, it fails to update with VMaccessforlinux extension issue.
Turned on the boot diagnostics to do a serial console, but the serial console also not working properly, constantly throws messages.
Please suggest as to how I should login or create a new user with same privileges.

Regards,
Karan

Comment: I would suggest you start with this doc and go through all the options suggested. If that doesn't help let me know and we can look into it further 

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-ssh-connection

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried all those steps.

Comment: What error messages you are seeing the serial console?